# jQuery - append() does not work inside forEach()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `forEach` loop that generates `5` elements, what I want to do is to print the content of the array in the DOM. For that, I am using `append()` method in `jQuery` it works, however, it shows only the last element of the array.

Here is the code:

```
array.forEach(printFiveElem => {

   var section = `<div id="2759794" class="section"><div class="row"></div></div>`
   $("#2759794").html(section);
   $("#2759794 .row").append(`<div class="col"><h6 class="temp2">`+printFiveElem.val+`</h6></div>`);

 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "id" attributes have to be **unique**. Your code uses the same "id" on each iteration.

Comment: @Pointy even if I use the class for example `$(".row")` it does not change anything

Comment: everytime you loop you call ` var section = `<div id="2759794" class="section"><div class="row"></div></div>`
   $("#2759794").html(section);` again. So you are overwriting the previous loop, I think. Put these two lines before the foreach

Comment: @BarryThomas your conclusion solved my issue, thanks !

Comment: @Folky.H No problem, have made the same mistake myself :)